# colorseekbar not move in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-seekbar

i have one fragment it contains one custom color seekbar and gridview . but when try to scroll seekbar its not moving . this fragment is of viewpager .

```
 <com.example.app.ColorSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/icon_color"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/icon_color"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/grid_bg_new"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"></GridView>
```

Please help me how can i accomplish viewpager move as well as seekbar move. when i move seekbar pager must not move and when i swipe page then seekbar must not move.

i also put

```
icons_pager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

seekbar class

```
    public ColorSeekBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0, 0);
    }

    public ColorSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0, 0);
    }

    public ColorSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr){
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public ColorSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    protected void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        applyStyle(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public void applyStyle(int resId){
        applyStyle(getContext(), null, 0, resId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        mViewWidth = widthMeasureSpec;
        mViewHeight = heightMeasureSpec;

        int speMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        if(speMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST){
            if(mIsShowAlphaBar){
                setMeasuredDimension(mViewWidth,mThumbHeight * 2 +  mBarHeight * 2  + mBarMargin);
            }else{
                setMeasuredDimension(mViewWidth,mThumbHeight + mBarHeight);
            }
        }
    }



    protected void applyStyle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes){
        mContext = context;
        //get attributes
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ColorSeekBar, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        int colorsId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.ColorSeekBar_colors, 0);
        mMaxValue = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ColorSeekBar_maxValue,100);
        mColorBarValue = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ColorSeekBar_colorBarValue,0);
        mAlphaBarValue = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ColorSeekBar_alphaBarValue,0);
        mIsShowAlphaBar = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ColorSeekBar_showAlphaBar, false);
        mBackgroundColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.ColorSeekBar_bgColor, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mBarHeight = (int)a.getDimension(R.styleable.ColorSeekBar_barHeight,(float)dp2px(10));
        mThumbHeight = (int)a.getDimension(R.styleable.ColorSeekBar_thumbHeight,(float)dp2px(30));
        mBarMargin = (int)a.getDimension(R.styleable.ColorSeekBar_barMargin,(float)dp2px(5));
        a.recycle();

        if(colorsId != 0) mColors = getColorsById(colorsId);

        setBackgroundColor(mBackgroundColor);

        init();

        //init color
        pickColor(mColorBarValue);
        setAlphaValue();

    }

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    private int[] getColorsById(int id){
        if(isInEditMode()){
            String[] s=mContext.getResources().getStringArray(id);
            int[] colors = new int[s.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++){
                colors[j] = Color.parseColor(s[j]);
            }
            return colors;
        }else{
            TypedArray typedArray=mContext.getResources().obtainTypedArray(id);
            int[] colors = new int[typedArray.length()];
            for (int j = 0; j < typedArray.length(); j++){
                colors[j] = typedArray.getColor(j,Color.BLACK);
            }
            typedArray.recycle();
            return colors;
        }
    }


    private void init() {
        //init l r t b
        realLeft = getPaddingLeft() + mPaddingSize;
        realRight = getWidth() - getPaddingRight() - mPaddingSize;
        realTop = getPaddingTop() + mPaddingSize;
        realBottom = getHeight() - getPaddingBottom() - mPaddingSize;

        //init size
        mThumbRadius = mThumbHeight / 2;
        mPaddingSize = (int)mThumbRadius;
        mBarWidth = realRight - realLeft;

        //init rect
        mColorRect = new Rect(realLeft ,realTop,realRight,realTop + mBarHeight);

        //init paint
        mColorGradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, mColorRect.width(), 0, mColors, null, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
        mColorRectPaint = new Paint();
        mColorRectPaint.setShader(mColorGradient);
        mColorRectPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mTransparentBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w,h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
        mTransparentBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }



    public ColorSeekBar(Context context, float x1, float x2) {
        super(context);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        init();
        float colorPosition = (float) mColorBarValue / mMaxValue * mBarWidth;

        Paint colorPaint = new Paint();
        colorPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        colorPaint.setColor(pickColor(colorPosition));
        int[] toAlpha=new int[]{Color.argb(255, mRed, mGreen, mBlue),Color.argb(0, mRed, mGreen, mBlue)};
        //clear
        canvas.drawBitmap(mTransparentBitmap,0,0,null);

        //draw color bar
        canvas.drawRect(mColorRect, mColorRectPaint);

        //draw color bar thumb
        float thumbX = colorPosition + realLeft;
        float thumbY = mColorRect.top + mColorRect.height() / 2;
        canvas.drawCircle(thumbX,thumbY , mBarHeight / 2 + 5, colorPaint);

        //draw color bar thumb radial gradient shader
        RadialGradient thumbShader  = new RadialGradient(thumbX,  thumbY,  mThumbRadius, toAlpha, null, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
        Paint thumbGradientPaint = new Paint();
        thumbGradientPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        thumbGradientPaint.setShader(thumbShader);
        canvas.drawCircle(thumbX, thumbY, mThumbHeight / 2, thumbGradientPaint);

        if(mIsShowAlphaBar){

            //init rect
            int top = (int)(mThumbHeight+ mThumbRadius + mBarHeight + mBarMargin);
            mAlphaRect = new Rect(realLeft,top,realRight,top + mBarHeight);

            //draw alpha bar
            Paint alphaBarPaint = new Paint();
            alphaBarPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            LinearGradient alphaBarShader = new  LinearGradient(0, 0, mAlphaRect.width(), 0, toAlpha, null, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
            alphaBarPaint.setShader(alphaBarShader);
            canvas.drawRect(mAlphaRect,alphaBarPaint);

            //draw alpha bar thumb
            float alphaPosition = (float) mAlphaBarValue / 255 * mBarWidth;
            float alphaThumbX = alphaPosition + realLeft;
            float alphaThumbY = mAlphaRect.top + mAlphaRect.height() / 2;
            canvas.drawCircle(alphaThumbX, alphaThumbY, mBarHeight / 2 + 5, colorPaint);

            //draw alpha bar thumb radial gradient shader
            RadialGradient alphaThumbShader  = new RadialGradient(alphaThumbX,  alphaThumbY,  mThumbRadius, toAlpha, null, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
            Paint alphaThumbGradientPaint = new Paint();
            alphaThumbGradientPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            alphaThumbGradientPaint.setShader(alphaThumbShader);
            canvas.drawCircle(alphaThumbX,alphaThumbY, mThumbHeight/2, alphaThumbGradientPaint);
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if(isOnBar(mColorRect, x, y)){
                mMovingColorBar = true;
            }else if(mIsShowAlphaBar){
                if(isOnBar(mAlphaRect, x, y)){
                    mMovingAlphaBar = true;
                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
             if(mMovingColorBar){
                 float value = (x - realLeft) / mBarWidth * mMaxValue;
                 mColorBarValue =(int)value ;
                 if (mColorBarValue < 0) mColorBarValue = 0;
                 if (mColorBarValue > mMaxValue) mColorBarValue = mMaxValue;
             }else if(mIsShowAlphaBar){
                 if(mMovingAlphaBar){
                     float value = (x - realLeft) / mBarWidth * 255;
                     mAlphaBarValue = (int)value;
                     if (mAlphaBarValue < 0 ) mAlphaBarValue = 0;
                     if (mAlphaBarValue > 255 ) mAlphaBarValue = 255;
                     setAlphaValue();
                 }
             }
            if(mOnColorChangeLister != null && (mMovingAlphaBar || mMovingColorBar))
                mOnColorChangeLister.onColorChangeListener(mColorBarValue, mAlphaBarValue,getColor());
            invalidate();
             break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            mMovingColorBar = false;
            mMovingAlphaBar = false;
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }


    /**
     *
     * @param r
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @return whether MotionEvent is performing on bar or not
     */
     private boolean isOnBar(Rect r, float x, float y){
         if(r.left - mThumbRadius < x && x < r.right + mThumbRadius && r.top - mThumbRadius < y && y < r.bottom + mThumbRadius){
             return true;
         }else{
             return false;
         }
     }

    /**
     *
     * @param position
     * @return color
     */
     private int pickColor(float position) {
         float unit = position / mBarWidth;
         if (unit <= 0.0)
             return mColors[0];

         if (unit >= 1)
             return mColors[mColors.length - 1];

         float colorPosition = unit * (mColors.length - 1);
         int i = (int)colorPosition;
         colorPosition -= i;
         c0 = mColors[i];
         c1 = mColors[i+1];
//         mAlpha = mix(Color.alpha(c0), Color.alpha(c1), colorPosition);
         mRed = mix(Color.red(c0), Color.red(c1), colorPosition);
         mGreen = mix(Color.green(c0), Color.green(c1), colorPosition);
         mBlue = mix(Color.blue(c0), Color.blue(c1), colorPosition);
         return Color.rgb( mRed, mGreen, mBlue);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param start
     * @param end
     * @param position　
     * @return
     */
    private int mix(int start, int end, float position) {
        return start + Math.round(position * (end - start));
    }

    public int getColor() {
        if(mIsShowAlphaBar) return Color.argb(mAlpha, mRed, mGreen, mBlue);
        return Color.rgb( mRed, mGreen, mBlue);
    }


    public int getAlphaValue(){
        return mAlpha;
    }


    /**
     * @return color with alpha value
     */
    public int getColorWithAlpha(){
        return Color.argb(mAlpha, mRed, mGreen, mBlue);
    }


    public interface OnColorChangeListener {
        /**
         * @param colorBarValue between 0-maxValue
         * @param alphaValue between 0-255
         * @param color return the color contains alpha value whether showAlphaBar is true or without alpha value
         */
        public void onColorChangeListener(int colorBarValue, int alphaValue, int color);
    }

    /**
     * @param onColorChangeListener
     */
    public void setOnColorChangeListener(OnColorChangeListener onColorChangeListener){
        this.mOnColorChangeLister = onColorChangeListener;
    }


    public int dp2px(float dpValue) {
        final float scale = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return (int) (dpValue * scale + 0.5f);
    }

    /**
     * Set colors by resource id. The resource's type must be color
     * @param resId
     */
    public void setColors(int resId){
        setColors(getColorsById(resId));
    }

    public void setColors(int[] colors){
        mColors = colors;
        invalidate();
        setAlphaValue();
        if(mOnColorChangeLister != null)
            mOnColorChangeLister.onColorChangeListener(mColorBarValue, mAlphaBarValue,getColor());
    }

    public int[] getColors(){
        return mColors;
    }

    public boolean isShowAlphaBar(){
        return mIsShowAlphaBar;
    }

    private void refreshLayoutParams(){
        mThumbHeight = mThumbHeight < 2? 2:mThumbHeight;
        mBarHeight = mBarHeight < 2? 2:mBarHeight;

        int singleHeight = mThumbHeight + mBarHeight;
        int doubleHeight = mThumbHeight *2 + mBarHeight * 2 + mBarMargin;

        if(getLayoutParams().height == -2) {
            if(mIsShowAlphaBar){
                getLayoutParams().height = doubleHeight;
                setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
            }else{
                getLayoutParams().height = singleHeight ;
                setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
            }
        }else if (getLayoutParams().height >= 0){
            if(mIsShowAlphaBar){
                getLayoutParams().height = doubleHeight;
                setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
            }else{
                getLayoutParams().height = singleHeight;
                setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
            }
        }
    }

    public void setShowAlphaBar(boolean show){
        mIsShowAlphaBar = show;
        refreshLayoutParams();
        invalidate();
        if(mOnColorChangeLister != null)
            mOnColorChangeLister.onColorChangeListener(mColorBarValue, mAlphaBarValue,getColor());
    }

    /**
     * @param dp
     */
    public void setBarHeight(float dp){
        mBarHeight = dp2px(dp);
        refreshLayoutParams();
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * @param px
     */
    public void setBarHeightPx(int px){
        mBarHeight = px;
        refreshLayoutParams();
        invalidate();
    }

    private void setAlphaValue(){
        mAlpha = 255 - mAlphaBarValue;
    }

    public void setAlphaBarValue(int value) {
        this.mAlphaBarValue = value;
        setAlphaValue();
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getMaxValue() {
        return mMaxValue;
    }

    public void setMaxValue(int value) {
        this.mMaxValue = value;
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * set margin between bars
     * @param mBarMargin
     */
    public void setBarMargin(float mBarMargin) {
        this.mBarMargin = dp2px(mBarMargin);
        refreshLayoutParams();
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * set margin between bars
     * @param mBarMargin
     */
    public void setBarMarginPx(int mBarMargin) {
        this.mBarMargin = mBarMargin;
        refreshLayoutParams();
        invalidate();
    }


    /**
     * Set the value of color bar, if out of bounds , it will be 0 or maxValue;
     * @param value
     */
    public void setColorBarValue(int value) {
        this.mColorBarValue = value;
        invalidate();
        if(mOnColorChangeLister != null)
            mOnColorChangeLister.onColorChangeListener(mColorBarValue, mAlphaBarValue,getColor());
    }

    /**
     * set thumb's height by dpi
     * @param dp
     */
    public void setThumbHeight(float dp) {
        this.mThumbHeight = dp2px(dp);
        refreshLayoutParams();
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * set thumb's height by pixels
     * @param px
     */
    public void setThumbHeightPx(int px) {
        this.mThumbHeight = px;
        refreshLayoutParams();
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getBarHeight() {
        return mBarHeight;
    }

    public int getThumbHeight() {
        return mThumbHeight;
    }

    public int getBarMargin() {
        return mBarMargin;
    }

    public float getColorPosition() {
        return mColorBarValue;
    }


}
```

Comment: post your ColorSeekBar class

Comment: check edited question

Comment: this color seekbar works fine in activity but not working in viewpager fragment

Comment: @sunita visit here : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131958/sunita-and-harshad